# Linux shared library that unloads itself

Tags: c++, c, linux, shared-libraries

My goal is to hook several glibc functions inside a certain group of processes located at specific path. There are multiple methods to do so (gdb, strace, etc). But I need it to be made automatically and reliably on earliest stage so I won't miss a single call. So I decided to go with `LD_PRELOAD` method. And I need it to be done automatically without any user intervention, so injecting `LD_PRELOAD` into environment is kinda fragile and may be overridden by user. So I decided to specify my library inside `/etc/ld.so.preload` - this works just fine.

Inside my library ctor code, I check if the process I'm in is the one I need and do necessary hooking, otherwise it's a no-op and library is just a dead weight.

```
__attribute__((constructor)) void my_lib_ctor()
{
  if (is_relevant_process())
  {
    do_the_wiring();
  }
}
```

The library does not export any symbols and everything inside is hidden by default (`-fvisibility=hidden` compiler flag), so there are no any real dependencies to my library from any process. So in case of injection into unrelated process it can be safely unloaded.

Unload is required for update procedure - if library is to be updated, it shouldn't be loaded into long-running processes - otherwise they will crash on library replacement (which is expected). Processes of interest are short-lived and user-started, so impact on them is negligible.

The problem is - I don't know how to unload it safely. I was thinking about `dlclose`, but calling it from the library itself will result it returning from the call back to the library code which will be already unloaded.

And if there are other methods for *automatically and reliably* hooking glibc calls on the early stage (before app's `main()` execution) without touching the app of interest itself, I'll be glad if you let me know about them (slight modification of OS configs, e.g. preload, is OK). Thanks!

Comment: Two-stage approach? Use a small, stable library for LD_PRELOAD, then load the big one from there.

Comment: Also, why would updating a library crash whatever has it loaded? The running code keeps the old file open, the new code gets the new file.

Comment: *otherwise they will crash on library replacement (which is expected)* Only if your update process overwrites the existing library.  Delete it first.

Comment: Arkadiy, Andrew, I tried deleting it first, but it crashes process anyway

Comment: Write the new library version to a temporary file (on the same disk) and move it into the correct place. Should be no risk of crashes (or anyone failing to load it).

Comment: @hydrechan This seems relevant:  https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/74165/how-to-upgrade-shared-library-without-crash

Comment: @AndrewHenle, yeah, I've read it and this is exactly what I currently do: 1. unlink/rm existing one; 2. put new one into same location.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have some misunderstandings, and what you're asking for just doesn't make sense:

> Inside my library ctor code, I check if the process I'm in is the one I need and do necessary hooking, otherwise it's a no-op and library is just a dead weight.

And the work to unload it, rather than just leaving it there doing nothing, it **more** weight.

> Unload is required for update procedure - if library is to be updated, it shouldn't be loaded into long-running processes - otherwise they will crash on library replacement (which is expected).

This can only happen if you erroneously *overwrite* the library file, rather than *replacing* the file. The latter can be performed by installing a temp file to the same directory and performing the `rename` function (equivalently, the `mv` command) with the old file as the target.

> And if there are other methods for automatically and reliably hooking glibc calls on the early stage

Your focus on "reliably" sounds suspiciously close to wanting to use this mechanism to impose policy/access control in a way that potentially malicious applications can't get around. This is **fundamentally impossible** at the library level. You would need to run them in some kind of real sandbox to achieve that (e.g. by replacing the files with wrapper scripts that invoke them in the appropriate sandbox).

Comment: I tried to unlink/delete original library before placing the update - still crashes the processes. Can I diagnose what is the actual cause of the crash - accessing mmapped file that was deleted or maybe something else?

Comment: gdb should be able to see it just fine as long as the process is still running. You could also keep a hard link to the old file around, or even just a copy.

Comment: @hydrechan the normal upgrade process on all linux distributions involves replacing libraries that are being used by processes, and it never crashed one (the old one is kept around as an anonymous inode by the filesystem driver until it is no longer used). Something fishy is going on within your lib, and you should debug that.

Comment: I tried to make a test loop where it is being updated over and over, and it doesn't crash using either method (rm+cp, cp+mv). But this is artificial case because I'm replacing old file with the identical copy. I will build multiple versions of the library and will try replacing versions randomly at high pace in the loop.